# Deleting array of pointers to pointers pointing to object

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I want to ask one simple question in my program i making some kind of system, for dynamic allocation I am taking array of pointers to pointers like this

```
Vehicle **temp=new Vehical*[countVehicle];
```

then

```
temp[countVehicle-1]=new Car();
```

You must have understood what I am trying to do. The problem comes when deleting memory. Can you please tell me how to delete memory in this case.

Comment: Use a vector of smart pointers.

Comment: I want it without vectors because I havent seen that topic

Comment: They're easier and safer (and can be used almost exactly like the pointers). Better to learn now instead of trying to manage memory manually.

Comment: @user3215228 Here is code to delete a vector of smart pointers:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for ( int i = 0; i < countVehicle; ++i)
{
    delete temp[i];  // assert destructor is virtual!
}
delete[] temp;
```

Make sure destructor in base class, `Vehicle`, is declared virtual so the correct destructor is called when deleting objects via base class pointer, as it take place in example above.

```
class Vehicle {
public:
    //...
    virtual ~Vehicle() {}
};
```

---

However you should consider using a `std::vector` of smart pointers, e.g

```
{
  std::vector< boost::shared_ptr<Vehicle> > v;
  v.push_back( boost::shared_ptr<Vehicle>( new Car()));
  v[0]->run(); // or whatever your Vehicle can do
  //...
} // << When v goes out of scope the memory is automatically deallocated.
```

This will ease memory management.

Answer (score 1):

If you know for sure that the pointers in temp are NULL or a valid allocated Car then:

```
for(int i = 0; i < countVehicle; ++i)
    delete temp[i];
delete[] temp;
```

This will only work correctly if Vehicle has a virtual destructor. Otherwise you will not properly destroy each Car.

Comment: yes thats why it was not running due to virtual destructor can u please modify your answer and also brief about virtual destructor

Comment: @user3215228 what do you need to ebe explained about virtual destructor?